# How can I represent a Use Case Table Diagram when I have two user types capable of initiating it?

Tags: uml, use-case

I have two users in my program, one's a Programmer and the other's an Administrator. The Administrator is capable of doing everything the Programmer can do, but also has some additional roles (such as adding new users).

When writing my table diagram, with a use case such as "Edit Program", I need to have it initiated by either the Programmer or the System Administrator (because they are both capable of doing it).

I've been trying to find something which would show me how that should be written, but everything I've seen is just for a single initiating user. So I have a few questions:

1. When two users can initiate a use case, how would I write that? Would I put something like "Initiated by Programmer or Administrator", would I need to have it written in two lines ("Initiated by Programmer / Initiated by Administrator"), would I need two tables, etc.?
2. When listing the user in the flow of events, how would I do that? The only way I can see it is by having two separate tables and replacing all of them in those tables. Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no use case table diagram in UML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of this does depend on the format of the tables for your use cases. There are many different formats out there, all slightly different.

> When two users can initiate a use case, how would I write that? Would I put something like "Initiated by Programmer or Administrator", would I need to have it written in two lines ("Initiated by Programmer / Initiated by Administrator"), would I need two tables, etc.?

One of the fields that I often have in a use case description in tabular format is "Actor". This lists all of the actors in the use case and a brief description of their role. In your case, your description that states that the use case can be initiated by an Administrator or Programmer is probably sufficient.

> When listing the user in the flow of events, how would I do that? The only way I can see it is by having two separate tables and replacing all of them in those tables. Is that correct?

I wouldn't have two separate tables. You can refer to the initiating user as "the initiator". If you've identified that a person with the role of Administrator or Programmer can initiate the use case, then this would refer to whoever it is that initiated the use case. If it doesn't necessarily have to be the initiator, then you can simply refer to the role(s) that can execute the case. I would avoid having two use case tables that differ only by role unless there were other differences in the use case flow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: stop making every use case worry about who started it.

Unless the use case is about permissions or roles or who's using it stop letting that be the focus.

When your use case is about editing the program I expect the user to be labeled user. If editing the program is a protected activity I expect the user will use some kind of authentication and secure permission system that will sort out if this user is authorized or not.

Done this way not every use case user has to be labeled as admin, programmer, tester, or guest.

Answer (score 1):

If an Administrator can do everything that a Programmer can do, then an Administrator **is a** Programmer.

Inheritance amongst actors is quite possible, even though they are never classes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can "derive" the administrator actor from Programmer actor via generalization relationship.

A good example of that is [here](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/useCaseDiagram.htm).